# daily update of a view and save it away

Tags: sql

Hi is there an automatic way, that a view could be updated daily by the system and then the result will be stored in another database / view?
The background is that I created a report for stock and this is only seen per day and it could be different on another day. 
I then like to save the results in another table to see the history. 
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

you could try a [MATERIALIZED VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html)

and have a trigger on a the target source table if the time meets the end of the day, you would trigger the view update.

the content of the materialized view is stored and not processed at query time.

Comment: @MichaelSievers: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016